# Raising Signals and using Handlers in C

Tags: c, handler, signals

I have a program that I need to use signals and handlers with. I have two child processes that are supposed to receive a user defined signal and one is supposed to do nothing with the signal, while the other is supposed to print out some generic message, sleep and then print out another message indicating that the halt is over. The one child process that's supposed to do nothing with the signal is supposed to be the one to raise the signal.

I am pretty sure the signal is rose with the notation `signal(SIGINT, handler);` so I would simply put that within the function that is defined by the one child process, but how do I "send" the signal to both processes? How can I say under a set of conditions that the one process receives the signal and does what it is told by the handler while the other receives the signal and does nothing?

I was reading about how `kill(pid, handler)` would be able to send the designated process to the handler, but whenever I try it, it tells me that argument 1 of kill makes integer from pointer without a cast.

My program is a reader/writer program that pretty much tests concepts without a definite purpose, and right now, is all within one source doc, but will be split off into a reader source to define the reader process' functions, a writer source, which will define the writer process' function and then the main source that creates the two child processes. I will also have a header file that will define all the necessary constants and function prototypes, but right now, if I can just get it working from within this one source, I can figure out later how to separate it into multiple sources.

Comment: [`signal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal) registers a signal handler; it doesn't raise a signal.

Comment: as a start, it looks like most of your questions would be answered from the GNU C Manual's chapter on signals if you haven't looked at it already: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signal-Handling.html

Comment: @spade78 Thank you for the reference - I will be sure to look through this to better understand what's going on with signals. My instructor primarily gives me code to try to look through and decipher what's going on, which is why I thought `signal` raises the signal because that's what it appeared to be doing when I was running through a debugging session of a given piece of code. I never came across this resource while digging throughout the net for explanations.

It's unfortunate however that people insist on punishing me for my lack of understanding though.

Comment: You might also just want to look into the standard, 7.14.1 of  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Comment: @Newwisdom01 - it's not punishment, it's just a tough call sometime when dealing with homework on where to draw the line between help and supplying the answer outright.

Comment: FWIW you are on the right track.  `signal` will install your handler.  `kill` will send your signal.  As for your error, `kill` takes a pid_t and an int; that int is your signal.  At least two of the defined signals are reserved for user defined signals.  The pid is going to returned from `fork`.

Comment: @Duck: Where I draw the line is actual code or pseudocode. Correcting a misunderstanding of how to use an API is what we're supposed to be doing here and which is a trivial thing. I think the bigger challenge in this homework problem is figuring out how to get each child process to discover the PID of the other. I've been thinking about that for the past hour and still haven't figured that part out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based off of my reading of the [GNU C Manual's chapter on signals](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signal-Handling.html#Signal-Handling).

Like Kerrek says, signal() allows processes to register with the OS that there is a signal of interest that the process would like the OS to deliver to it. Once the signal has been generated, the sighandler_t argument to signal() specifies what the process will do, either default handling (SIG_DFL), ignore the signal (SIG_IGN), or something custom as defined by the handler function that is passed to signal(). That handler function is where you define the behaviors of one process to do something with it when the signal is delivered to it.

The second processes job is to raise the specified signal after a period of sleep() so it'll be using the kill(pid, signum) function to do so which takes the PID of the intended recipient and signal to deliver to said recipient.

Comment: The reference you provided earlier cleared up a lot of misconception I had about what signal actually was. Thank you for that. For right now, I think that by making my processes' ID variables global, attaining access to them and using signal by means of kill is working, but I haven't been able to test it because my current code won't compile. That is not the scope of my question here though, so I'll plug away at it and try to get it to work. Then I can worry later about accessing everything when the functions are split into different source files.